# SharePoint Access denied message on page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint page with multiple tiles on it. Some of the tiles are access restricted to some users. If restricted user looks at the page they see an "access denied" or an "Error" message on page instead of tiles. Is there a way to remove this message and make them see a bank space instead of these "access denied" messages? These are circled in below image.

[the items below tiles are which i want to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx7Jw.png)

Comment: I think you forgot the image. Also you may get more luck asking on https://serverfault.com/ as this sounds more like an admin question than a software development question.

Comment: @JeffUK : i am totally new to this site / or to asking for help via forums. Apologies - i will re post in relevant forum.

Comment: No worries, we review posts from new users, we're here to help!

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer !! 
I had to click the entire web-part containing the tiles in Page edit mode and in web part properties - advanced tab , update target Audience with relevant user ids.